# IIS7 Rewrite Rules How to Add: ignore extensions

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I just added an new rewrite rule so I can redirect pages like:

www.Domain.com/PartnerNameHere/

**to:**

www.Domain.com/LandingPage?page=PartnerNameHere

However now all axd references are not working.

How do I set: ignore extensions for css,jpg,png axd..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current your match pattern for `RewriteUserFriendlyURL1` is `^([^/]+)/?$`, which makes no concession for extensions (it's matching any queries with a single URI segment).

If `PartnerNameHere` can never contain a `.`, then changing your match pattern to `^([^/.]+)/?$` should be sufficient.

If, however, you only want to block those *specific* extensions, you'll need to use this: `^(?![^/]+?\.(?:css|png|jpg|axd)$)([^/]+)/?$`

Comment: Thanks .. I tried that and got this error:

HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The expression "^([^/]+)/?(?<!\.(?:css|png|jpg|axd))$" has a syntax that is not valid.

Comment: @aron - I'm not sure why, but the Rewrite rule doesn't seem to support negative lookbehind assertions. I've updated it to use a negative lookahead assertion that I've tested in IIS. I'll update it again if I can get lookbehinds to work.

Comment: I've asked about the neg. lookbehind issue on the IIS forums and I'll update my answer should I get a response - http://forums.iis.net/p/1175656/1971981.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I also needed, much appreciated.